# Gradle: where to define commons properties in a project with subprojects?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project similar to this one:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications_multi_project.html#run_the_init_task

Same directory schema.

Every subproject in its `build.gradle` use the `maven-publish` and use a setup similar to this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'org.gradle.sample'
            artifactId = 'library'
            version = '1.1'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to define is a common `groupId` and `version` for every project but I don't know where to define it.

On some docs, I found that I can use a `build.gradle` with an `allProjects` section in the root directory, but I don't have it, maybe should I create it?

But more a general question, how can I define common properties to share across subprojects?

Comment: if you don't have a `build.gradle` in the parent of the subproject, how did you specify that all the projects are subprojects actually?

Comment: I have `settings.gradle` where I have `rootProject.name = 'foobar'` and `include('app', 'list', 'utilities')` that are the subprojects. Look at the link I posted, the directory schema is the same because I have used the init gradle plugin too.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with the `build.gradle` file will work.

You can either specify

```
subprojects {
  group = "org.gradle.sample"
}
```

or alternatively

```
allprojects {
  group = "org.gradle.sample"
}
```

Please note that both (*subprojects* and *allprojects*) are all lower-case!
For your current situation it should not matter which of the both you use. If the main (root) project would also publish code, there would be the difference that *subprojects* only works for the subprojects but not the root project and *allprojects* - you guess it - works also for the root project.

Comment: it doesn't work, whatever property I set (groupId or a foobar property) I get an error `Could not set unknown property 'groupId' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`.  The `build.gradle` I created is in the root dir of the project.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: the name of the property it is not `groupId` but just `group`. I updated the answer accordingly.